# Alternative for Particle Photon's Timer

Tags: interrupt, timers

I am converting a program made for particle photon to a Mega, everything is working except for the interrupt timer. The code that is of concern is (it's a .cpp file being included in the main .ino)

```
MyClass::MyClassConstructor(){
    messageTimer = new Timer(20, &MyClass::send, *this);
}
```

The documentation for this method is [here](https://docs.particle.io/reference/device-os/firmware/photon/#software-timers).

Does anyone know a way to convert this to Arduino? There is the Timer library, but I can't really use the update method as the timer is in an instance of a class.

Comment: why do you need to convert code? ... why don't you instead describe how you want the code to function

Comment: The code, that you show us, only instantiates the timer with an interval and it's callback function. This also can be done for example with the Timer1 library. Please describe further where exactly you have a problem with that

Comment: try TimerOne library